# Is there a pure JavaScript (no HTML) way for a dialog window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement something similar to jQuery's [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), but AFAIK, all the examples require an HTML object to wrap (or be) the content. Is there a reliable way to implement a dialog from pure JavaScript? I mean, the only change I want to make on the HTML code should be `<script src=".."></script>`. Is this possible?

Comment: alert('hi"); is pretty close to that...

Comment: yes, I meant except `alert` :) maybe creating the HTML object inside JavaScript?

Comment: You can dynamically add it to the DOM using JavaScript. If that's not an option for you, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You're asking how to create a JavaScript dialog with no HTML, then suggest making the HTML inside JavaScript, which of course is using HTML.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan good point. I just want to test my js code without touching the html files. but you made me realize I will have to touch them at some point anyway :)

Comment: I mean, you can of course make HTML in JavaScript. In fact, you can do it with jQuery UI Dialog: [`$('<div id="dialog">Show me in a dialog</div>').dialog();`](https://jsfiddle.net/0op4ax9w/) should show a dialog with text in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.prompt()` method. [For more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

```js
prompt('Enter your age');
```